# Maintain aspect ratio when filling img within div

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following recurring problem that I've not been able to find an effective solution for. Others must have come across the same issue but despite searching I cannot seem to find the exact issue, although it must be very commonplace. Hopefully this question will be useful for many developers.

I am aiming to fill and center an image that is within a container div. The images may be portrait, landscape or square and have different aspect ratio's/sizes that are all variable. The container div has a fixed height but a percentage based width, so is also variable.

I am finding that with the below code the images are scaled extremely large, and any adjustment to the code results in stretching of the aspect ratio, which is not desirable. Of course cropping is inevitable but I'd like to find the best way to minimise this and display all images in the best light possible. I've added a red background to the container div as I do not want any of this to show in any instance.

I'm open to any resolutions that might be out there.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rddtona2/)

[Live Example of problem](http://workshop.oakdesignstudio.com/dwl/) (scale browser to see)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/500/">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/1000/">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud No? Would that make difference?

Comment: if you use bootstrap then you can do it easily with `class="img-responsive"` in you `<img>` div.You can use grid system for perfect responsive.

Comment: Do you know of any examples I can check out? Might it be possible to apply this to my current setup (without using bootstrap)?

Comment: Having looked into Bootstrap's .img-responsive class, it's not actually helping with the issue I described.